# Multiline parsing pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I want to parse a standard JAVA exception in ELK stack 6.3.2 version which looks like :

```
2018-09-04 05:29:03.955 [default task-38] ERROR c.r.e.u.util.MongoConnectionUtil.createMongoUser - Exception occured while creating mongo userCommand failed with error 11000: 'User "asdf" already exists' on server 192.168.1.33:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "User \"asdf\" already exists", "code" : 11000, "codeName" : "DuplicateKey" }
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 11000: 'User "qwer" already exists' on server 192.168.1.33:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "User \"asdf\" already exists", "code" : 11000, "codeName" : "DuplicateKey" }
    at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:114) ...
```

My filebeat.yml has the configuration :

```
filebeat.inputs:

- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - C:\logs\test.log
  multiline.pattern: '^[[:space:]]+(at|\.{3})\b|^Caused by:'
  multiline.negate: false
  multiline.match: after
```

and my logstash.conf input looks like :

```
input {

beats {
    port=>5044
        codec => multiline {
               pattern => "^\s"
              what => "previous"
}
}
```

But logstash says failed to parse the pattern, in fact it crashes with exception. If I remove the `codec` configuration then only, the first line of the exception is getting parsed. I have also put the same question at https://discuss.elastic.co/t/multiline-parsing-patterns/147171 but no response.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change:
 `multiline.negate` to `true`.
and I don't sure what you are trying to achieve with the pattern but it seem you should go with:

```
multiline.pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
```

Further more you don't need to use multiline in the logstash - just go simple with:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044            
    }
}
```

In summery in order to catch all the log I would change your Filebeat config to:

```
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - C:\logs\test.log
  multiline.pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
```

A bit of explanation:
When we choose `negate:true` and `match: after` we tell FileBeat:

> Consecutive lines that don’t match the pattern are appended to the
>   previous line that does match.

In other words - It tells FileBeat to harvest every line which start with the given pattern and stop when this pattern appear again in the beginning of a new line.
For this pattern `^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}` if you get this 2 exceptions:

```
2018-09-04 05:29:03.955 [default task-38] ERROR c.r.e.u.util.MongoConnectionUtil.createMongoUser - Exception occured while creating mongo userCommand failed with error 11000: 'User "asdf" already exists' on server 192.168.1.33:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "User \"asdf\" already exists", "code" : 11000, "codeName" : "DuplicateKey" }
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 11000: 'User "qwer" already exists' on server 192.168.1.33:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "User \"asdf\" already exists", "code" : 11000, "codeName" : "DuplicateKey" }
    at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:114) ...

2018-09-04 05:30:00.000 [default task-38] ERROR c.r.e.u.util.MongoConnectionUtil.createMongoUser - Exception occured while creating mongo userCommand failed with error 11000: 'User "asdf" already exists' on server 192.168.1.33:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "User \"asdf\" already exists", "code" : 11000, "codeName" : "DuplicateKey" }
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 11000: 'User "qwer" already exists' on server 192.168.1.33:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "User \"asdf\" already exists", "code" : 11000, "codeName" : "DuplicateKey" }
    at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:114) ...
```

It would catch every exception as a different entry log. If you log more stuff and you want filebeat to harvest only Error, It is a different thing. In our program we harvest all of it and query by severity (i.e. Error, Info, Warn and etc)

Comment: I see that in the document https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html that for a pattern of the type `abb` its false please explain and about the exception what about `caused by` clause will this be recorded with your pattern ?

Comment: I edited a bit - hope it answers the first part of your question. I don't understand why you will include the caused by part. Every exception starts with a Timestamp of the format i wrote (i.e. [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) which suppose to do the trick and pretty intuitive in my taste.

Comment: Did you try what I have suggested?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see the logs getting appended as one string

Comment: Did you restart the service? -i just double checked, it is the correct config

Comment: Tried this as well. My logs look identical to the samples in this answer and the log lines are still appended individually.